# Is it possible to change the default color of the items in scale_size in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I would like to change the default color of the `scale_size_manual()` in `ggplot2` independent of the type of the data in the dataframe.

Is this possible?

For example I would like all of the items in the size legend to be of color `"red"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
> p <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(x = mpg,y = disp,size = cyl)) + geom_point()
> p + scale_size_continuous(guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = "red")))
```

Oddly, `override.aes` seems to not like the American spelling of `color`. Might have to track that down and submit a small patch...